# How to get the current user id in the Rails router (routes.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to get the user ID of the current user in the Ruby on Rails router (app/config/routes.rb)?

Comment: Do you want to create a different route for current-user id?

Comment: Exactly. I'd discovered that I can do `root to: 'posts#index', user_id: 4` and have 4 passed as the user_id: to the index action (so that I've got an effective route of `users/4/posts` rather than `users/posts`).

Comment: you can try this, get 'users/:id/posts', to: 'photos#index' and manage the rediction un controller using params[:id] and checking with current user.

Comment: If I want it to be the root route, would I do: `get 'users/:id/posts', to: 'posts#index', as: root`?

Comment: yes you can take root 'posts#index', even if is done, if still rake routes shows index without id, change the action name other than index, something like 'user_post_index' and create a route and change route to ' get 'users/:id/posts', to: 'posts#user_post_index', then root 'posts#user_post_index'

Comment: Ah, so the controller action names are convention, not requirement?

Comment: yes I think so, the index action by convention not taking id to it.

Comment: If you find that answer useful, please accept it, I will post as an answer.

Comment: I already made an answer please upvote and also accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an action in your posts controller 'user_post_index',then you can try this,

```
get 'users/:id/posts', to: 'posts#user_post_index'
```

and manage the rediction in controller using params[:id] and checking with current user.

```js
def user_post_index
  if params[:id].present?
   if params[:id] == current_user.id
     ***** do some stuff ****
   else
     ***** do some stuff ****
   end
  end 
end
```

```
 root 'posts#user_post_index' and make it as root.
```

Comment: The other think I needed to do was to create a template for user_post_index.html.erb